# How does the computer count?

Tags: c, fseek

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* f;
    f=fopen("book.txt","w");
    char* sentence="0123456789";
    fprintf(f,"%s\n",sentence);
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
    int a=ftell(f);
    printf("%d\n",a);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

I have the code above which prints out 12 when I run it. why is it not 11 (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,\0) instead of 12?

EDITED: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,\r\n)

Comment: "0123456789" + ('\n':CR and LF)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows systems, the newline is actually *two* characters: Carriage-return and the newline characters (`"\r\n"`).

So you have your ten characters from the string you write out, plus the two for the newline.

Comment: Isn't it insane that `\n` inserts two characters? Does the standard allow this, or again, it's just MSVC++ being MSVC++ (and crap)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#History

Comment: @H2CO3: Translating `\n <-> \r\n` during I/O is an option of the Microsoft C-Runtime Library (see [Text and Binary Mode File I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktss1a9b(v=vs.71).aspx)). Unfortunately, the default mode is "Text".

Comment: @MartinR So it's allowed, but at the same time MS being MS. I see, thanks. One more reason I'll never touch Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[Running on Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations), perhaps? On OS X and Linux, this prints 11 for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a windows system, you are printing two newline characters: #13 and #10 by adding an extra `\n`. Remove it ad see what you get:

```
fprintf(f,"%s",sentence);
```